# For what design reason TCanvas.StretchDraw is not working as expected for the TIcon?

Tags: delphi, canvas, icons, delphi-2009, stretch

Recently I've discovered that `TCanvas.StretchDraw` will not work as expected for object which is a `TIcon` instance (quick look at `TIcon.Draw` and `DrawIconEx` method tells why). Delphi [help](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Graphics_TCanvas_StretchDraw.html) acknowledges that fact. I know the workaround but I do not know the reason behind such design decision in VCL. Does anyone know why they decided to left `TIcon` untouched in this matter?

Comment: I wouldn't expect answer other than *"That's by design"*.

Comment: This just reflects the underlying API. If you want to `StretchDraw`, put the image in a bitmap and do it from there. This is not a Delphi issue. All your tags, but really this is a `winapi` question.

Comment: @David, this is a Delphi implementation issue. The `StretchDraw` calls `TGraphic.Draw` method and if `TIcon.Draw` doesn't care about passed rectangle size (but takes for the `DrawIconEx` only its position), it's only Delphi implementation fault.

Comment: @TLama So, how should `TIcon.Draw` be implemented then?

Comment: @David, the same way you suggest your workaround. If the passed rectangle size would be different from the icon size, the icon would be flushed to a temporary bitmap and rendered as stretched.

Comment: @TLama So you agree that the underlying API does not support this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I would expect that you look at the code before saying that this is not Delphi issue. @TLama why to compare size at all? Why not to call `DrawIconEx(ACanvas.FHandle, Left, Top, Handle, Right - Left, Bottom - Top, 0, 0 , DI_NORMAL)` ? There is no need passing icon to temporary bitmap at least not explicitly. The line of code which I've shown is enough.

Comment: Wodzu, to be honest, I never tried to stretch icons this way, but it seems to work, so I would say yes. That might be enough. @David, just tried the proposed code from the previous comment and it works, at least on Windows 7, so it seems `DrawIconEx` supports stretching. In all cases it's Delphi which doesn't implement stretching for `TIcon.Draw`. If they were use `DrawIconEx` or a temporary bitmap doesn't matter, it's just ignored.

Comment: Does that stretch? Does it not clip?

Comment: @David, it does stretch.

Comment: Clearly I am talking nonsense. Sorry.

Comment: This is probably because `DrawIconEx` didn't exist back in the earlier versions of the OS (according to MSDN, `DrawIconEx` wasn't available until Win2K). Since Delphi supported Win95 until recently, and `DrawIconEx` didn't seem to be available there, it makes sense they didn't use it. (It could have been updated later when Win95 support was dropped, but probably was just overlooked.)

Comment: @Ken Supported in Win95, and NT3.5. I had the same thought, but it seems it's wrong. http://www.jasinskionline.com/windowsapi/ref/d/drawiconex.html

Comment: @Wodzu It does seem odd. Perhaps the original author just made a mistake and once the error had leaked out the decision was made not to change the code because that would break existing codebases. It's obviously simple enough for you to work aruond.

Comment: @David: Thanks. I checked MSDN, but didn't have the link you posted. It's probably still along the same lines, though; the VCL stayed 16/32 bit compatible for quite a while, and `TIcon` was created for D1. It was probably just never updated later. Agreed that there's an easy workaround.

Comment: Easy workaround and simple answer. It's by design. Also, I don't think that it would break existing VCL codebase, because why would one explicitly call `StretchDraw` for a `TIcon` which actually does no stretch at all at this time. Yes, it may break someones code, but I don't think it would affect VCL.

Comment: @TLama Even if it broke the VCL, Emba control that so they could fix it. But nobody suggests that a change would break the VCL. The change would break existing code.

Comment: @David, I wouldn't even call it break. If I call somewhere in my code `StretchDraw`, I expect the output to be stretched, so it's just my fault if I call `StretchDraw` for a `TIcon` passing there however big rectangle expecting it to be rendered in its original size.

Comment: @TLama Library developers tend not to want to change behaviour of existing routines. Irrespective of whether or not the behaviour is sane.

Answer (score 1):

Icons are not regular bitmaps. This is mostly due to historical design and technical reasons.

It did make sense at time when icons were small 32x32 pixels large and 16 colors (good old days!) that icons were never to be stretched on screen.

But there is also a "common sense" technical reason. Such small bitmaps are usually very hard to be re-sized by an algorithm (and default GDI strech algoritm is very fast but produces also very bad result in respect to [other interpolation modes, e.g. available with GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), so it was decided to embed a *set of icons* within the executable, as resources: one icon per size. The strech process benefits of being done at design time, at pixel level, by an icon designer. And - back those days - it was also much less resource consuming to use dedicated icons, with a reduced color palette.

Since you are supposed to have a set of icons with a pre-defined size for each, you do not need to use StrechDraw, but just select the right icon to display.

So if you want to display an icon with a given size, ensure you pickup the right size, or get the biggest icon and upsize it, using a temporary bitmap - or [`DrawIconEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648065). Or, even better, do not use icons, but a bitmap, or a vectorial drawing if you expect huge picture size.